# HTML - Changing hours dropdown based on time

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

So I have two dropdowns as follows:

The first based on start time:

```
<select class="form-control" type="time" name="starttime" id="starttime" value="">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Start time</option>
    <option value="00:10:00">10:00am</option>
    <option value="00:11:00">11:00am</option>
    <option value="00:12:00">12:00pm</option>
    <option value="00:13:00">1:00pm</option>
    <option value="00:14:00">2:00pm</option>
    <option value="00:15:00">3:00pm</option>
    <option value="00:16:00">4:00pm</option>
    <option value="00:17:00">5:00pm</option>
    <option value="00:18:00">6:00pm</option>
</select>
```

And the second based on number of hours from the starting time:

```
<select class="form-control" name="sessions.0.hours" id="hours" label="No. of Hours">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Hours</option>
    <option value="4">4 hours</option>
    <option value="5">5 hours</option>
    <option value="6">6 hours</option>
    <option value="7">7 hours</option>
    <option value="8">8 hours</option>
    <option value="9">9 hours</option>
    <option value="10">10 hours</option>
    <option value="11">11 hours</option>
    <option value="12">12 hours</option>
</select>
```

What I'd like is for the 2nd dropdown to change based on the start time selected so that the number of hours after the starting time doesn't go beyond closing time (10pm). Examples:

- A 10am start allows you to choose any number of hours from the minimum (4 hours) to the maximum (12 hours).
- A 4pm start allows you to choose number of hours from the minimum (4 hours) up to 6 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can help you.

HTML

```
<select class='form-control', type="time" name="starttime" id="starttime" value="">
  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Start time</option>
  <option value="00:10:00">10:00am</option>
  <option value="00:11:00">11:00am</option>
  <option value="00:12:00">12:00pm</option>
  <option value="00:13:00">1:00pm</option>
  <option value="00:14:00">2:00pm</option>
  <option value="00:15:00">3:00pm</option>
  <option value="00:16:00">4:00pm</option>
  <option value="00:17:00">5:00pm</option>
  <option value="00:18:00">6:00pm</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="sessions.0.hours" id="hours" label="No. of Hours">
  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Hours</option>
</select>
```

JS JQuery

```
function selectStartTime(val){
 switch(val){
  case "00:10:00":
   hoursAvailable(10);
   break;
  case "00:11:00":
   hoursAvailable(11);
   break;
  case "00:12:00":
   hoursAvailable(12);
   break;
  case "00:13:00":
   hoursAvailable(13);
   break;
  case "00:14:00":
   hoursAvailable(14);
   break;
   case "00:15:00":
   hoursAvailable(15);
   break;
   case "00:16:00":
   hoursAvailable(16);
   break;
   case "00:17:00":
   hoursAvailable(17);
   break;
   case "00:18:00":
   hoursAvailable(18);
   break;
  default:
   console.log("default");
 };
};

var CLOSINGTIME = 22;

function hoursAvailable(startTimeInt){
  var diff = CLOSINGTIME - startTimeInt;
  var options = "<option value='' disabled selected hidden>Hours</option>";
  var hour = 4;
  for (i = 0; i < diff-3; i++) { 
    options += "<option value="+hour+">"+hour+" hours</option>";
    hour++;
  };

  $("select#hours").html(options);
};

$("select#starttime").on("change", function(){
  selectStartTime(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<select class='form-control', type="time" name="starttime" id="starttime" value="" onchange="myfunction(this)">
                            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Start time</option>
                            <option value="00:10:00">10:00am</option>
                            <option value="00:11:00">11:00am</option>
                            <option value="00:12:00">12:00pm</option>
                            <option value="00:13:00">1:00pm</option>
                            <option value="00:14:00">2:00pm</option>
                            <option value="00:15:00">3:00pm</option>
                            <option value="00:16:00">4:00pm</option>
                            <option value="00:17:00">5:00pm</option>
                            <option value="00:18:00">6:00pm</option>
                          </select>


<select class="form-control" name="sessions.0.hours" id="hours" label="No. of Hours">
                           <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Hours</option>
                           <option value="4">4 hours</option>
                           <option value="5">5 hours</option>
                           <option value="6">6 hours</option>
                           <option value="7">7 hours</option>
                           <option value="8">8 hours</option>
                           <option value="9">9 hours</option>
                           <option value="10">10 hours</option>
                           <option value="11">11 hours</option>
                           <option value="12">12 hours</option>
                         </select>
```

**js**

function myfunction(val){
    myswithcase(val[val.selectedIndex].innerHTML);

}

```
function myswithcase(term){
    switch(term){
     case "10:00am":
        //  do not do anything
           break;
           case "4:00pm":
               hoursAvailable("4:00pm".split(':')[0]) 
           break;
          default:
           console.log("default");
         };
    }


function hoursAvailable(val){
    console.log(val)
    var number = parseInt(val) + 2;
    var a = Array.from(document.getElementById('hours'))
    var b = a.filter(function(rm){return rm.value > number})
    b.forEach(function(rm){
        rm.setAttribute('disabled','disabled')
})
}
```